Working Residence Permit without Anmeldung
I am living in Berlin on the Opportunity Card visa and am looking for advice on how to convert this to a Residence Permit in order to work as I will be receiving a job offer. However, I am unable to get Anmeldung at this time as the apartment I am living in will now allow me to register my address here. I'm afraid this will prevent me from working if it is a requirement to have Anmeldung to get my residence permit to start work.
Does anyone have any advice on this topic or know if there is any way around this? What I can provide is a written contract from my roommate (whom I am subletting, so not officially from the owner), and maybe make an Anmeldung appointment in the future to be able to say for my residence permit application that I haven't been able to get an Ameldung appointment yet but I have a rental agreement and will apply for the Anmeldung soon. Would this suffice, or is official Anmeldung absolutely required?

A lot of things are predicated on being properly registered, German bureaucracy doesn't really have a place for you without that and it is legally required in any case, quite apart from your visa or residence permit status. Importantly, your landlord / roommate is also required to help you register, there is no such thing as deciding whether they want to let you register or not. The problem is that if you press the issue, you just risk revealing to the owner that your roommate is subletting illegally and end up without a place to stay rather than an immediate solution.

To be a bit more precise, usually people that are homeless (and thus no anmeldung) fall through the cracks of "the system" as a lot of things work by post and having an address, it is common that homeless people with mental health issues in Germany are in that condition, partially, because of not having an address. It cannot be overstated how important it is to have Anmeldung in Germany.


What I can provide is a written contract from my roommate (whom I am subletting, so not officially from the owner), and maybe make an Anmeldung appointment in the future to be able to say for my residence permit application that I haven't been able to get an Ameldung appointment yet but I have a rental agreement and will apply for the Anmeldung soon. Would this suffice, or is official Anmeldung absolutely required?

Honestly, that won't work. German bureaucrats won't fall for this kind of shenanigans, you will require a proper registration for a lot of things. Also consider the fact that you would present a lease that's older than 14 days or somehow need to account where you had been staying until now, thus revealing that you failed to register when you should have and are liable for a fine.
I know that finding a place to stay can be tough in large German cities but what you really need is a proper home, not a way to game the system.
